# communication between socket and RMI

Tags: java, rmi, serversocket

I have a fire alarm sensor system which takes periodic updates of temperature,co2 level and some more factors.Then these data are sent to server. This communication is done by socket programming.In the socket server side these data are written into a text file.

Then this data is read by a RMI server and according to monitors(clients that monitor the sensors) request those data are displayed.

One of the request of the monitor is that the count of the sensors that are connected and count of the monitors.I have taken the sensor count by adding them into a arraylist on the socket side(Note that we can add more sensors at any given time).

Now when the monitor asks for the count of sensors I need to pass that value of sensor count without writing it into a text file and reading it back,how do I solve this.

Comment: You make it available to the clients via an RMI method.

Comment: well thats the case I don't want to use rmi it's communication between rmi and socket(The data I want to send is in socket server)

Comment: 'Communication between RMI and socket' is meaningless. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Here's the full link to the question http://www.mediafire.com/file/mc4j2ssbbh3x413/Assign1.pdf

Comment: Matter that forms part of a question must be included in the question, but what part of 'you may use Java Socket programming to communicate between the server and the sensors and Java RMI to manage the communication between the server and the monitors (clients)' didn't you understand? Nothing there about 'communication between RMI and socket'.